# My array of NSDictionaries returns the dictionaries with ONLY the keys and no values. How can I fix this?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have an array of NSDictionaries. Right now this array only contains two dictionaries for simplicity.

As I am stepping through the code, each `NSDictionary` is created properly and **contains the expected values**... I access this array (which is filled in my model) through:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sDictionaries;`

I access this property in my controller through:

`NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:sLocator.sDictionaries]` but when I take a look inside `array`, it only contains the keys and **not** the values (which I already saw while the dictionary was created in my model).

Any help in passing this array of `NSDictionary` objects from my model to my controller is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the code where I iterate through some received data and place it in `NSDictionary` objects.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
sDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

int i = 0;
//iterate through each element, get the string, then add to the array
//I know for this example I am receiving 10 element objects which are NSStrings. 
//The first string is the key of the dictionary and the next 4 strings are the values.
//Then all the objects are removed from arrayOfObjects and a new dictionary is made
for(Element *element in nodes)
{
    [mArray addObject:[element content]];

    if(i%5 != 0)
    {
        [arrayOfObjects addObject:[element content]];
    }

    if(i%5 == 0)
    {   
        [idArray addObject:[element content]];
    }

    if([arrayOfObjects count] >= 4)
    {
       //Here is where the dictionary is created then added to the array. 
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arrayOfObjects forKey:[idArray lastObject]];
        [sDictionaries addObject:dictionary];

        [arrayOfObjects removeAllObjects];
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: How do you create and fill `sDictionaries`?

Comment: can you check this ? NSLog(@"class %@",[[sLocator.sDictionaries] class]). could be dictionary.

Comment: @trojanfoe - I only do this once, not multiple times. I had also tried doing `NSArray *array = sLocator.sDictionaries`.

@coverback - Like so:

    `NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arrayOfObjects forKey:[idArray lastObject]];`
           

 `[sDictionaries addObject:dictionary];`

`arrayOfObjects` is just a mutable array containing 4 strings. `idArray` is also a mutable array containing strings.

@thndrkiss - yeah I'll check tomorrow morning, I've been working on this project all day and I'm calling it quits for now. I'll let you know when I check

Comment: Sorry forgot to add this:

Here is where I create `sDictionaries`:


    `sDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];`

Comment: I think everybody here could be more helpful, if you had added your code, how do you create the array, the dictionaries and how do you add them to the array.

Comment: Yeah, like @Mert says, add more code directly to the question. There is still something missing, the code from your comment cannot account for the behaviour. Post also how you test the content of the filled `array`.

Comment: @Mert - I edited the post and put the requested code.

Comment: There is no such thing as a dictionary with only keys and no values. What do you actually have?

Comment: When the dictionary is created in my model is has both keys & values. When I access the array (that contains 2 dictionaries) and perform objectForKey on each dictionary it shows no values. When I print a description of the dictionary it shows `someKey {     } ` when it should show `someKey{value1, value2, value3, value4}` and it does in my model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line sucks.
`NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arrayOfObjects forKey:[idArray lastObject]];`

You removed allObjects by `removeAllObjects` after add it to the dictionary, so the object it self is removed. Try to change that line to

`NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:arrayOfObjects] forKey:[idArray lastObject]];`

Comment: Yeah I want to remove all the objects after the dictionary is created. Doesn't the dictionary no longer rely on the contents of `arrayOfObjects` if I created it before removal?

I'll give what you suggested a try.

Comment: @JohnnyGamez: It no longer depends on the *value of the variable* `arrayOfObjects` — that is, if you assigned a new array to the variable, the dictionary wouldn't care — but it does still depend on the *contents of the array itself*. So when you mutate the contents of the array — such as through `removeAllObjects` — that affects the array everywhere it is referenced, including the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @onevcat! This solved my problem.

I guess I had a misunderstanding of how `NSDictionary` objects retain their values. I will have to look into documentation about this stuff.